# Implementing CodeMirror Syntax Highlighter

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to make use of [**this**](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) Syntax highlighter. I have tried to implement [**their example**](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/contrib/sql/index.html) and I always seem to get this error in firebug:

> place is not a function
>       else place(div);

Here is my code, I thought it was a path issue, but everything looks right:

```
<textarea id="code1" rows="20" cols="20">
select * from where this = done
</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/js/codemirror.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var editor = new CodeMirror('code1', {
  height: "150px",
  parserfile: "codemirror/contrib/sql/js/parsesql.js",
  stylesheet: "css/sqlcolors.css",
  textWrapping: true
});

</script>
```

If you look at the source code of that example page, its similar to mine yet, the text in the text area doesn't get highlighted and I always get that error.

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the code that initializes CodeMirror to the following and I think it will work:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea('code1', {
  height: "150px",
  parserfile: "codemirror/contrib/sql/js/parsesql.js",
  path: "codemirror/js/",
  stylesheet: "css/sqlcolors.css",
  textWrapping: true
});
```

The important parts are using `CodeMirror.fromTextArea` rather than `new CodeMirror` and providing a value for `path` in the object passed into `CodeMirror.fromTextArea`.

Comment: The important parts being to use "CodeMirror.fromTextArea" and to supply a "path" property as part of the options.

Comment: Yes. I should have been more explicit. I've now changed my answer.